# Valgrind message : Address XXX is in a r-x mapped file <fielpath> segment

Tags: c, gcc, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am learning C for malloc and free heap memory related to self-defined structure.

### The problem I met

For below code I constantly got `segment fault`.
Using `valgrind` to analysios showed : `==12999==  Address 0x108b4b is in a r-x mapped file <folder_path> segment
==12999==`

full output :

```
Name : Amy 
Date of Birth: 1989 9 21
Name : echo 
Date of Birth: 1989 9 21
Name : echo 
Date of Birth: 1989 9 21
Name : echo Address 0x5580be70e270
Date of Birth: 1989 9 21
Their address : 0x5580be70e260 0x5580be70e264 0x5580be70e268
Name : echo Address 0x5580be70e270
Date of Birth: 1989 9 21
Their address : 0x5580be70e260 0x5580be70e264 0x5580be70e268
free p->name 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

### The analysis I did

I use `valgrind` to try to find where results this:
`valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./person2`
The output is shown as :

```
Their address : 0x522d040 0x522d044 0x522d048
Name : echo Address 0x522d050
Date of Birth: 1989 9 21
Their address : 0x522d040 0x522d044 0x522d048
free p->name 
==12999== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==12999==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12999==    by 0x108894: Person_destruct (person2.c:33)
==12999==    by 0x108A2F: main (person2.c:74)
==12999==  Address 0x108b4b is in a r-x mapped file /folder/path segment
==12999== 
freed p->name 
free p 
freed p 
==12999== 
==12999== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12999==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==12999==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,052 bytes allocated
==12999== 
==12999== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==12999==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12999==    by 0x108817: Person_construct (person2.c:16)
==12999==    by 0x1089CC: main (person2.c:64)
==12999== 
==12999== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12999==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==12999==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12999==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12999==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12999==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12999== 
==12999== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12999== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What I understand is that `*p3` points to the exact same memory piece as `p1` (which proved by `Person_address_print()`, thus I only explicitly  destruct `p1` to avoid twice destruct the same heap memory.)
I also tried to let `p3->name = "ada";` to ensure the allocated string is still within the previous length (3) or explicitly set `p3 == NULL` before calling `Person_destruct(p1)`; the same segment fault error occurs :(

### The code

Here is the code. The code basically does:
a. self-defined a structure `Person`
b. (in `main`)construct objects for `Person`, destruct them and print related attributes.

```
//  person.h
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
typedef struct
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int date;
    char * name; // name is a ponter b/c name length is unknown
} Person;
Person * Person_construct(int y, int m, int d, char * n);
void Person_destruct(Person *p);
void Person_print(Person * p);
#endif
```

```
#include "person.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
Person *Person_construct(int y, int m, int d, char *n)
{
    Person *p = NULL;
    p = malloc(sizeof (Person));
    if (p == NULL) // malloc failed
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    p->year= y;
    p->month = m;
    p->date = d;
    p->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(n) + 1));
    // + 1 for the neding char '\0'
    if ((p->name) == NULL)// malloc failed, just return
    {
        free(p); 
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(p->name, n);
    return p;
}

void Person_destruct(Person *p)
{
    // p->name must be freed befoer p is freed
    if (p->name != NULL)
    {
        printf("free p->name \n");
        free(p->name);
        printf("freed p->name \n");
    }

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("free p \n");
        free(p);
        printf("freed p \n");
    }
}

void Person_print(Person *p)
{
    printf("Name : %s \n", p->name);
    printf("Date of Birth: %d %d %d\n", 
        p->year, p->month, p->date);
}


void Person_address_print(Person *p)
{
    printf("Name : %s Address %p\n", p->name, &(p->name));
    printf("Date of Birth: %d %d %d\n", 
        p->year, p->month, p->date);
    printf("Their address : %p %p %p\n", 
        &(p->year), &(p->month), &(p->date));
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Person * p1 = Person_construct(1989,9, 21, "Amy");
    Person_print(p1);

    Person * p3 = p1;
    p3->name = "echo";
    Person_print(p3);
    Person_print(p1); // p1's name should have changed to "echo".
    Person_address_print(p1);
    Person_address_print(p3);


    Person_destruct(p1);
    // p3 is pointing to the same memory of p1, should not destruct(p3)

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

### The environment I am running

gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

valgrind-3.13.0

Thanks so much for any clue!

Comment: `p3->name = "echo";` Why do you do that? That's the likely cause of your problem. It not only causes a memory leak because the original `p3->name` memory is lost but it also causes a problem when `free(p->name)` is called as `p->name` is no longer a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @kaylum you are right!! Thanks so much! I wish i could upvote your advice as the final answer! Happy holiday!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@kaylum 's answer inspires me. 
I forget C's  **string literal** concept, where if I did `p3->name = "echo"`, I manually let `p3->name` points to a string literal and its previously pointed char array, which is malloc at heap memory, will be lost.
This is the reason I am failed when `free(p->name)`;

Thanks @kaylum !

Comment: So what did you change afterwards?